# @track array of objects

Tags: lightning-web-components, track

Let's say I have `@track dataSource[]` which contains objects `{id,price}`
Why if I for example change the value

```
this.dataSource[1].price = 1234;
```

i can't get changes in markup?
Markup

```
<lightning-datatable
            data={dataSource} 
            columns={columns} 
            key-field="lotId">
   </lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `@track` works differently for different Types. For Objects, it tracks changes to properties. Arrays are treated differently, you need actually re-assign the property, so that UI is updated.

```js
this.dataSource[1].price = 1234;
this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource];
```

In the following example with Object UI would be updated.

```js
@track user = {name: 'John', age: 25};

ageUser() {
   this.user.age += 1;
}
```

Comment: Note, as of Spring '20, `@track` is no longer required to make arrays or objects reactive when reassigned. In the examples above, `this.dataSource` would not need to be decorated, but the `user` object would still need to be decorated with `@track`.